# Error launching remote program failed to get the task for process

Tags: xcode4.2, ios5

I just upgraded from XCode 4.1 to 4.2 and when I run the app on the iPhone it says: error launching remote program failed to get the task for process... (the process number changes every time)

Any ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to use the wrong type of Certificate. I was trying to debug it, but I had the Distribution certificate installed.